# sqlite3.OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8 column

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with this row of information, the ù should really be a '-'

```
sqlite> select * from t_question where rowid=193;
193|SAT1000|having a pointed, sharp qualityùoften used to describe smells|pungent|lethargic|enigmatic|resolute|grievous
```

When I read that row from python I get this error, what am I doing wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo_error.py", line 8, in <module>
    cur.execute(sql_string)
  sqlite3.OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'posit' with text 'having a pointed, sharp qualityùoften used to describe smells'
```

Python File:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('sat1000.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql_string = 'SELECT * FROM t_question WHERE rowid=193'
cur.execute(sql_string)
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 23):

Set `text_factory` to `str`:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('sat1000.db')
conn.text_factory = str
```

This will [cause `cur` to return `str`s](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.text_factory) instead of automatically trying to decode the `str` with the `UTF-8` codec.

I wasn't able to find any chain of decodings and encodings that would transform `'ù'` to a hyphen, but there are many possible unicode hyphens such as `u'-'`, `u'\xad'`, `u'\u2010'`, `u'\u2011'`, `u'\u2043'`, `u'\ufe63'` and `u'\uff0d'`, and I haven't ruled out the possibility that such a chain of decoding/encodings might exist. However, unless you can find the right transformation, it might be easiest to simply use `str.replace` to fix the string.

Correction:

```
In [43]: print('ù'.decode('utf-8').encode('cp437').decode('cp1252'))
—    # EM DASH u'\u2014'
```

So there are chains of decoding/encodings which can transform `'ù'` into some form of hyphen.

Comment: This won't work in the current version of Python 3.  See my answer below for another solution.

Answer (score 13):

The answer by unutbu won't work in current versions of Python 3.  Setting `conn.text_factory = str` won't do anything, since the default value of `text_factory` [is already](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)  `str`.

Probably the problem is that you have text in a database column that is not valid UTF-8.   By default, Python's `decode()` function throws an exception when it sees text like that.  But you can set a `text_factory` that tells `decode()` to ignore such errors, like this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('my-database.db')
conn.text_factory = lambda b: b.decode(errors = 'ignore')
```

Then the query should run without an error.

Answer (score 12):

`conn.text_factory = str` doesn't work for me.

I use `conn.text_factory = bytes`. reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23509002/6452438