# Python Encoding - Could not decode to utf8

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an sqlite database that was populated by an external program. Im trying to read the data with python. When I attempt to read the data I get the following error:

**OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8**

If I open the database in sqlite manager and look at the data in the offending record(s) using the inbuilt browse and search it looks fine, however if I export the table as csv, I notice the character £ in the offending records has become **Â£**

If I read the csv in python, the £ in the offending records is still read as **Â£** but its not a problem I can parse this manually. However I need to be able to read the data direct from the database, without the intermediate step of converting to csv.

I have looked at some answers online for similar questions, I have so far tried setting "text_factory = str" and I have also tried changing the datatype of the column from TEXT to BLOB using sqlite manager, but still get the error.

My code below results in the OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
conn.text_factory = str
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute('''SELECT xml_dump FROM hands_1 LIMIT  5000  , 5001''')
row = curr.fetchone()
```

All the records above 5000 in the database have this character problem and hence produce the error.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try decoding it to UTF-16?

Comment: I didn't, i'm new to programming, can you point me in the right direction of how I might try it?

Comment: Wait, why are you using a doc string there?

Comment: Im sorry I don't understand the question?

Comment: If I try that I get an error : NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined

Comment: Do you have the source code of that external program?

Comment: @Natecat isn't that how you do multiline string literals too? Nevertheless, his query also isn't multiline...

Typically i use double quotes for it because I'm a savage.

Comment: For people looking for a code to reproduce the error: `import sqlite3; sqlite3.connect(":memory:").execute("SELECT CAST(? AS TEXT)", (b"\xc3\x28",)).fetchall()`

Answer (score 25):

Python is trying to be helpful by converting pieces of text (stored as bytes in a database) into a python `str` object for you. In order to do this conversion, python has to guess what letter each byte (or group of bytes) returned by your query represents. The default guess is an encoding called utf-8. Obviously, this guess is wrong in your case.

The solution is to give python a little hint as to how to do the mapping from bytes to letters (i.e., unicode characters). You've already come close with the line

```
conn.text_factory = str
```

However (based on your response in the comments above), since you are using python 3, `str` is the *default* text factory, so that line will do nothing new for you (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.text_factory)).

What happens behind the scenes with this line is that python tries to convert the bytes returned by the query using the `str` function, kind of like:

```
your_string = str(the_bytes, 'utf-8') # actually uses `conn.text_factory`, not `str`
```

...but you want a different encoding where 'utf-8' is. Since you can't change the default encoding of the `str` function, you will have to mimic it some other way. You can use a one-off nameless function called a *lambda* for this:

```
conn.text_factory = lambda x: str(x, 'latin1')
```

Now when the database is handing the bytes to python, python will try to map them to letters using the 'latin1' scheme instead of the 'utf-8' scheme. Of course, I don't know if latin1 is the correct encoding of your data. Realistically, you will have to try a handful of encodings to find the right one. I would try the following first:

- `'iso-8859-1'`
- `'utf-16'`
- `'utf-32'`
- `'latin1'`

You can find a more complete list [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Another option is to simply let the bytes coming out of the database remain as bytes. Whether this is a good idea for you depends on your application. You can do it by setting:

```
conn.text_factory = bytes
```

Comment: SQLite always uses UTF-8. If a string is not actually UTF-8, is was wrongly inserted into the database in the first place.

Comment: @CL. That's true, but from the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/version3.html):  SQLite is not particular about the text it receives and is more than happy to process text strings that are not normalized or even well-formed UTF-8 or UTF-16. Thus, programmers who want to store IS08859 data can do so using the UTF-8 interfaces. As long as no attempts are made to use a UTF-16 collating sequence or SQL function, the byte sequence of the text will not be modified in any way.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was given a sqlite database produced with python2 in which the original contents were encoded as latin1. The line `conn.text_factory = str` seemed to work for reading this database in python2, but I am using python3 and that was failing. Your lambda function here worked great to get my program working.

Comment: I am using `pandasql ` to write query on `pandas` data-frame `out=ps.sqldf(query, locals())`. I am not connecting to any data-base. How to resolve it then??

Answer (score 6):

If the text in the database is actually mostly encoded in UTF-8, but you're still seeing this error (Could not decode to UTF-8), then the problem may be that one or more rows have bogus data that is not valid UTF-8.  By default, Python's `decode()` function throws an exception when it sees text like that.  If you are in this situation and want to simply ignore these errors, you can set up a `text_factory` like this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('my-database.db')
conn.text_factory = lambda b: b.decode(errors = 'ignore')
```

Comment: I am using `pandasql ` to write query on `pandas` data-frame `out=ps.sqldf(query, locals())`. I am not connecting to any data-base. How to resolve it then??