# sqlite3.OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8 column (Python,sqlite3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, sqlite, decode

I have a sqlite3 database with stuff in it, but im getting the error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'person' with text ' l�gal'

the ? is supposed to be "é". I dont get it.My project is set to UTF-8 encoding.I already tried:

```
con.text_factory = str   #con is my database object
```

However, I still get the same error.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Encoding - Could not decode to utf8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508153/python-encoding-could-not-decode-to-utf8)