# how to avoid the following issue, using python3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hello I have the following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

import pandas as pd
import re
import threading
import pickle

import sqlite3
#from treetagger import TreeTagger

conn = sqlite3.connect('Telcel.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select id_comment from Tweets')
id_comment = [i for i in cursor]
cursor.execute('select id_author from Tweets')
id_author = [i for i in cursor]
cursor.execute('select comment_message from Tweets')
comment_message = [i[0].encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1') for i in cursor]
cursor.execute('select comment_published from Tweets')
comment_published = [i for i in cursor]
```

That is working well in python 2.7.12, output:

```
~/data$ python DBtoList.py 
8003
8003
8003
8003
```

However when I run the same code using python3 as follows, I got:

```
~/data$ python3 DBtoList.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DBtoList.py", line 21, in <module>
    comment_message = [i[0].encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1') for i in cursor]
  File "DBtoList.py", line 21, in <listcomp>
    comment_message = [i[0].encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1') for i in cursor]
sqlite3.OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'comment_message' with text 'dancing music ������'
```

I searched for this line and I found:

```
"dancing music "
```

I am not sure why the code is working in python 2, it seems that python Python 3.5.2 is not able to decode this character at this line:

```
comment_message = [i[0].encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1') for i in cursor]
```

so I would like to appreciate suggestions to fix this problem, thanks for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 has no issue with the string itself if you store it using the Python sqlite3 API. I've set utf-8 as my default encoding everywhere.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute('create table Tweets (comment_message text)')
conn.execute('insert into Tweets values ("dancing music ")')
[(tweet,) ] = conn.execute('select comment_message from tweets')

tweet
```

output:

```
'dancing music '
```

Now, let's see the type:

```
>>> type(tweet)
str
```

So everything is fine if you work with Python `str` from the start.

Now, as an aside, the thing you are trying to do (encode utf-8, decode latin-1) makes very little sense, especially if you have things like emojis in the string. Look what happens to your tweet:

```
>>> tweet.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
'dancing music ð\x9f\x98\x9c'
```

But now to your problem: You have stored strings (byte sequences) in your database using an encoding different from utf-8. The error you are seeing is caused by the sqlite3 library attempting to decode these byte sequences and failing because the bytes are not valid utf-8 sequences. The only way to solve this problem is:

1. Find out what encoding was used to encode the strings in the database
2. Use that encoding to decode the strings by setting `conn.text_factory = lambda x: str(x, 'latin-1')`. This assumes you've stored the strings using latin1.

I would then suggest that you run through the database and update the values so that they now are encoded using utf-8 which is the default behaviour.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508153/python-encoding-could-not-decode-to-utf8).

I also highly recommend that you read [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) about how encodings work.

Comment: I really appreciate the support I will verify all of that aspects